# ¿Cómo crear carpeta y subir imágenes?

Tags: php

Tengo el siguiente codigo php el cual me permite subir multiples imagenes tomadas desde mi aplicacion android el nombre de mis fotografias es el ID del registro al que se le asignaron esas fotos.

Entonces lo que quiero lograr es que al momento de tomar **x** numero de fotos se cree una carpeta y que esa carpeta tenga por nombre el ID del registro asi si vuelvo a tomar mas fotos de ese registro se guarden solo en esa carpeta.

Ejemplo tengo el registro **1** y **2**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y hasta ahorita todas las fotos se almacenan en la carpeta upload y yo cree manualmente la carpeta **1_** pero quiero que todas las fotos que se tomaron del `ID` **1** esten en la carpeta **1_** y asi sucesivamente con cada registro como lo podria lograr este es mi codigo actualmente.

multi_upload.php

```
<?php

//adding headers for rest api
header("Content-Type: application/json");
header("Acess-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
header("Acess-Control-Allow-Methods: POST"); // here is define the request method

include 'dbconfig.php'; // include database connection file

$data = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"), true); // collect input parameters and convert into readable format


// getting the number of total number of files 
$countfiles = count($_FILES['file']['name']);
$file = $_FILES['file']['name'][0]; // getting first file

if(empty($file))
{
    // if file is empty show error
    $errorMSG = json_encode(array("message" => "please select image", "status" => false));  
    echo $errorMSG;
}
else
{

$upload_path = "upload/".$fileName."/"; // declare file upload path
$valid_extensions = array('jpeg', 'jpg', 'png', 'gif'); // valid image extensions - file extensions

// Looping all files 
for($i=0;$i<$countfiles;$i++){
    $fileName = $_FILES['file']['name'][$i];
    $tempPath = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'][$i];
    $fileSize  =  $_FILES['file']['size'][$i];

    $fileExt = strtolower(pathinfo($fileName,PATHINFO_EXTENSION)); // get image extension

    // check if the files are contain the vALID  extensions
    if(in_array($fileExt, $valid_extensions))
    {               
        //check file not exist our upload folder path
        if(!file_exists($upload_path . $fileName))
        {
            // check file size '5MB' - 5MegaByte is allowed
            if($fileSize < 5000000){

                //built-in method to move file to directory
                move_uploaded_file($_FILES ['file'] ["tmp_name"][$i], "$upload_path" . $_FILES ["file"] ["name"][$i]); // move file from system temporary path to our upload folder path 
                
                //insert into database table
                $query =  mysqli_query($conn,'INSERT into tb_image (name,id_plan) VALUES("'.$fileName.'","'.$fileName.'")');
                
            }
            else{       
                $errorMSG = json_encode(array("message" => "Sorry, your file is too large, please upload 5 MB size", "status" => false));   
                echo $errorMSG;
            }
        }
        else
        {       
            $errorMSG = json_encode(array("message" => "Sorry, file already exists check upload folder", "status" => false));   
            echo $errorMSG;
        }
    }
    else
    {       
        $errorMSG = json_encode(array("message" => "Sorry, only JPG, JPEG, PNG & GIF files are allowed", "status" => false));   
        echo $errorMSG;     
    }
   
   }
}

//if no error message show response
if(!isset($errorMSG))
{   
    echo json_encode(array("message" => "Imagenes registradas correctamente", "status" => true));   
}

?>
```

Yo lo que intente fue que en la variable `$upload_path` agrege el nombre del archivo y crei que asi podria generar la carpeta

`$upload_path = "upload/".$fileName."/"`

Y en el seccion de `move_upload_file` llame a la variable `path`

`move_uploaded_file($_FILES ['file'] ["tmp_name"][$i], "$upload_path" . $_FILES ["file"] ["name"][$i]);`

Pero no me funciona me podrian auxiliar

Answer (score 2, accepted):

La pregunta clave es ¿De dónde obtienes el *ID del registro*?

Con este dato puedes crear y/o establecer el directorio de subida de manera dinámica

```
//...Código previo

//Declarar una variable con el id del registro, de donde sea que lo obtengas
$idRegistro = 10;

//Crear la ruta
$upload_path = "upload/".$idRegistro;

//Validar si el directorio no existe para crearlo
if (!file_exists($upload_path)) {
    mkdir($upload_path, 0700);
}

//...El resto del código para cargar las imágenes
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, me funciono

Comment: Una pregunta y si quiero guardar las fotos en 2 ubicaciones diferentes si se puede?

Comment: Nunca lo he hecho pero supongo que si, sería necesario definir las dos rutas. En caso de que no funcione, podrías cargarla en una ubicación y luego usar la función `copy()` para copiarla de esa primera ubicación a otras diferentes... Cuestión de prueba y error.

Comment: Me podrias explicar como se utilizaria la funcion `copy()`

Comment: Ya realice la prueba y error al dar de alta 2 ubicaciones pero solo toma en cuenta la primera y la 2da la ignora incluso aun cuando estan en diferentes if

Comment: Esto es tema para otra pregunta... `copy()` recibe dos parámetros, el origen y el destino. Una vez cargada la imagen en la primera carpeta, ejecutas la función pasándole los dos parámetros. `copy($uploadPath, $laOtraRura);`. Ten en cuenta que ambas rutas deben contener el nombre de la carpeta y el nombre de la imagen con extensión incluida. [Revisa esta info](https://www.w3schools.com/php/func_filesystem_copy.asp) o [esta otra](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.copy.php) para que te hagas una idea.

Comment: Muchas gracias!

Ya lo consegui de la siguiente manera 
`$dir = opendir($upload_path);

//Recorro el directorio para leer los archivos que tiene
while(($file = readdir($dir)) !== false){    
//Leo todos los archivos excepto . y ..
     
if(strpos($file, '.') !== 0){   
//Copio el archivo manteniendo el mismo nombre en la nueva carpeta
copy($upload_path.'/'.$file, $path.'/'.$file);
}}`